# When does graph Laplacian have eigenvalue -1?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings, spectral-graph-theory

Consider an undirected graph $G$ with (symmetric) adjacency matrix $A \in \{0,1\}^{n \times n}$ and degree sequence $d = (d_i)$ where $d_i = \sum_{j} A_{ij}$. Assume that every node has degree at least $1$. Let $D = \text{diag}(d)$ be the diagonal matrix with the degrees $(d_i)$ on its diagonal. Define the Laplacian of the graph to be $L = D^{-1/2} A D^{-1/2}$.

It is not hard to see that $\sqrt{d} := (\sqrt{d_i})$ is an eigenvector associated with eigenvalue $1$. By Perron-Frobenius theory, it seems that $1$ is the Perron root (since its eigenvector has strictly positive entries), from which it follows that the spectral radius of $L$ is $1$, that is, for any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $L$, we have $|\lambda| \le 1$.

The question is:

- For what graphs, $L$ will have an eigenvalue $-1$?

  It seems to me that this question is related to graph-colorings. If we can color the nodes of the graph with $\{+,-\}$, so that adjacent nodes have different colors, then $(\pm\sqrt{d_i})$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $-1$. Since $2$-colorable graphs are exactly the bipartite graphs, it seems that a sufficient condition is being bipartite. But is this necessary?

EDIT: Please note that the Laplacian I defined above is a bit nonstandard. I am talking about the eigenvalues of $L$, whatever name you want to attach to it. (This version is actually quite standard among the people that use the Laplacian for spectral clustering.) If you think a Laplacian should be defined as $\widetilde{L} = I - D^{-1/2}A D^{-1/2}$, then please read my question as, "When does the Laplacian $\widetilde{L}$ has eigenvalue $2$"?

EDIT2: The conjecture is not true as I wrote if the graph is disconnected, since it could have a connected component that is bipartite, and many that are not. The bipartite component will contribute a $-1$ eigenvalue. So, let us add the assumption that the graph is connected.

Comment: According to sage $K_{2,2}$ has eigenvalues of the Laplacian: [4, 0, 2, 2] and $K_{3,3}$:  [6, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3]

Comment: The definition you are using of the graph laplacian is different / "wrong" --- it is either $D-A$, or the normalized version $I-D^{-1/2}AD^{-1/2}$. The Graph Laplacian is a well-known semidefinite matrix, whose smallest eigenvalue is $0$---so it can never have $-1$ as an eigenvalue.

Comment: @joro, There are many definitions of the Laplacian. The one I have mentioned in my post is a bit non-standard. (It is related to the symmetric Laplacian sometimes defined as $I - D^{-1/2} A D^{-1/2}$.) For the Laplacian that I defined, I still think what I wrote is correct.

Comment: @ suv....rit, A definition can't be wrong (it can be nonstandard). I am defining the Laplacian the way I mentioned above. You can rename it to whatever you like if you don't like the name. By the way, the eigenvalues of $I - D^{-1/2} A D^{-1/2}$ and  $D^{-1/2} A D^{-1/2}$ are very closely related (by an affine transform $x \mapsto -x+1$). You can reformulate my question in terms of that matrix.

Comment: What are the eigenvalues of K_{2,2} and K_{3,3} with your definition to test my implementation?

Comment: @joro, with my definition, both should have an eigenvalue $-1$.

Comment: @joro, in fact (for the $L$ defined above) they seem to have exactly one eigenvalue $1$ and one eigenvalue $-1$ with the rest of the eigenvalues being zero.

Comment: According to my implementation the graph with edges `[(0, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 5), (3, 6), (5, 6)]` has eigenvalue -1 and is not bipartite, not sure if this is correct. the min degree is 1.

Comment: @passerby51: which is why i put it in "..." marks ;-) --- just to alert readers to the non-standard usage in your question, because the other definitions linked to are vastly more prevalent.

Comment: @suv....rit, I understand, no hard feeling :)

Comment: Or maybe this one:  [(0, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 5), (3, 6), (5, 6)], [(0, 4), (0, 6), (1, 4), (1, 6), (2, 5), (3, 5), (4, 6)]

Comment: @joro, that is because the graph is disconnected, and it has a connected component which is bipartite (namely $(0,4)$). I should have mentioned that the graph is connected.

Comment: This one is connected and not bipartite:  `[(0, 3), (0, 5), (0, 6), (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6)]`

Comment: @joro, you second example also is disconnected and has a bipartite component $\{2,3,5\}$.

Comment: @joro, Are you sure? The computer says that the smallest eigenvalue is $-0.7953$ for you third example.

Comment: I am not sure, I put the degree **sequence** on the diagonal, should I put the degree of the vertices on the diagonal?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10903/discussion-between-passerby51-and-joro)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have $\det(tI-L) =\det(D^{-1}(tD-A))$. The matrix $D-A$ is positive semidefinite; it is the usual Laplacian in graph theory. The matrix $A+D$ is also positive semidefinite, and if the underlying graph $G$ has $n$ vertices
and exactly $b$ components are bipartite, its rank is $n-b$. Hence $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $L$ if and only if some component of $G$ is bipartite. (The matrix $A+D$ is often called the unsigned Laplacian.)

Comment: Thanks. Do you have source for that statement?

Comment: The first I found was http://www.hamilton.ie/skirkland/signless_bipartite_preprint.pdf; the result is much older than this source and is definitely folklore,

Comment: Thanks for the link. That one looks interesting as they seem to have results for approximately bipartite graphs too. Any other such reference is also welcome.

Comment: @passerby51 You might be interested in this as well: http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.7749 (does this count as a shameless plug?)